# Doubt in Concept of Unbalanced Force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, acceleration

My question is : Suppose a block of mass $m$ is kept on an ideal floor. To lift it, why I need to apply an upward force which is of magnitude $mg$? Force $mg$ is acting on the block in downward direction which is the force of gravity. If I apply an upward force $mg$ it just makes net force acting on the block zero. Then why the it would move upward? And why with zero acceleration

Comment: Suppose you applied an upward force of $mg+\delta$, where $\delta$ is vanishingly small.  Would that be enough to do the trick?